# Can't save changes in Alexa Developer Console

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, alexa-voice-service, alexa-slot

I can't save any changes in the Alexa Developer Console (for example if I want to change the endpoint) because I always receive this error:

> Provided eTag does not match with the resource's current eTag. Please
>   apply your changes on the latest version of the resource. Error code:
>   InvalidEtag

What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score -1):

1. Click Save
2. It says "Successful"
   Wait for a while. Do not Build it immediately.
3. Click "Build" and it will work successfully.